# CMD and VBA WScript.Shell max command length

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

I am currently working with long Strings that i have execute in a Shell. I know that the maximum length of a command in CMD is 8192 Characters. So it should be the same in VBA WScript.Shell:

```
Dim response As Integer
Dim objshell As Object
Set objshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
response = objshell.Run(ShellCommand, 1, True)
```

Since it just opens CMD it should also have a character limit of 8192. If that is true is it possible to have more characters by for example opening a .txt file in the Shell which includes the command itself? And what is the character limit for this then? I definitely need to pass more characters then 8192. I hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of testing I have found out myself that it is indeed possible to extend the maximum character length with the usage of a .txt or .bat file. All I did was take the ShellCommand, write it into for example .bat file and execute the .bat file through cmd. I have tested this for up to 16.000 Characters since it is enough for my application.

Comment: A batch file sends commands through the cmd interpreter, so its maximum command length does not increase. So in order to have achieved it, you must have reduced your must be a one line command, to splitting it into more than one line. This was exactly the reason why I asked for the content, to ascertain whether that option was possible. BTW, if you want this to be an official answer to the posed question, it would assist future readers, if you could provide the code you used in VBA, and an example of the way you wrote the batch file in order for it to work. Currently it is lacking that detail.

Comment: I have not yet implemented it in VBA but I tried with one whole String of up to 16000 characters and it was working fine with the bat file. Although the whole String was not displayed in cmd everything went through. But if I were to implement newlines into the String (would they not count as just another character?) how many characters or lines could I feed through cmd at once?